# Print Button not working in LiveCycle Html5 form

Tags: html, livecycle

I have a pdf form that has been converted to an Html5 form. In the conversion I dragged the print button to the form which generated this code:

```
xfa.host.print(1, "0", (xfa.host.numPages -1).toString(), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

The problem is that it doesn't do anything when clicked. It did work when it was a PDF form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So xfa.host.print() is not on the [list of methods supported by HTML5 Mobile Forms](https://helpx.adobe.com/livecycle/help/mobile-forms/scripting-support.html), however there is a workaround.  Try this code:

```
if ( xfa.host.appType == "HTML 5" )
{
    window.print();
}
else
{
    xfa.host.print(1, "0", (xfa.host.numPages -1).toString(), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```